# PHP: Looping through multidimensional object

Tags: php, oop

I use PDO to get data from database, and i need help in looping through objects and sub objects in PHP.

I have an Object that looks like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'Google Chrome' (length=13)
      public 'slug' => string 'google-chrome' (length=13)
      public 'content' => string 'Download Chrome browser for free.....' (length=37)
      public 'excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'logo' => null
      public 'status' => string 'draft' (length=5)
      public 'views' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'category_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created_at' => string '2017-06-12 16:59:22' (length=19)
      public 'updated_at' => string '2017-06-12 16:59:22' (length=19)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[10]
      public 'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'Avast' (length=5)
      public 'slug' => string 'avast' (length=5)
      public 'content' => string 'Avast antivirus is ......' (length=25)
      public 'excerpt' => string 'excerpt....' (length=11)
      public 'logo' => null
      public 'status' => string 'published' (length=9)
      public 'views' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'category_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created_at' => string '2017-06-12 17:45:18' (length=19)
      public 'updated_at' => string '2017-06-12 17:45:18' (length=19)
```

Is it possible to loop through results and display it in a table?
Is it possible to loop through results and display it in a table?

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Google Chrome</td>
    <td>draft</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Avast</td>
    <td>published</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Where did you get this `DB` object? All of its properties are private. Does it come from a framework?

Comment: @Don't Panic i have two classes: DB class performs all queries and returns data to Software class that does other tasks. In addition, DB class is called inside Software class.

Comment: Does it have an accessor to expose _results? or is DB itself iterable?

Comment: @Don't Panic Thank you so much, you asked me a good question. I can figure now what matter with this.

Comment: I think you just need to call a public method (like fetch or fetchAll) to get the result. Question: What is the output of this code?


$class = new ReflectionClass('DB');
$methods = $class->getMethods();
var_dump($methods);

Comment: @Daniel O after modifying my code and running var_dump() i got this :                                    array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'Google Chrome' (length=13)
..................
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[10]
      public 'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'Avast' (length=5)
     .............

Comment: That's good. Then just output the array of objects into a html table. 

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row->id . "\n<br>";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function html($text) {
    return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
}

// php template

<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= html($row->id) ?></td>
            <td><?= html($row->title) ?></td>
            <td><?= html($row->status) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```